# Is the Kendo UI syntax different between AngularJS 1.x and Angular 5?

Tags: angularjs, angular, kendo-ui

I have an Angular hybrid app that I'm migrating from AngularJS 1.64 to Angular 5. We are currently using Angular Material 1 for the AngularJS side and Angular Material 2, which has a different syntax, for the Angular 5 side.

The company I'm working with expressed their interest in moving to Kendo UI. My concern is that if the syntax Kendo UI uses is dependent upon the Angular version similar to how Angular Material is, then we'd end up making a bunch of "throw-away" HTML in the AngularJS templates that would have to be rewritten once it's upgraded to Angular 5.

So, is the Kendo UI HTML syntax vastly different between AngularJS 1.x and Angular 5? I see demos on their website for AngularJS, but not for Angular 5.

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/ that looks more like angular 5 than 1 to me

Comment: @Marco, I was on the "Kendo UI for JQuery" site which has a link to an AngularJS demo but not an Angular 5 demo. Sorry, I have no experience with Kendo UI. I'm confused why they have "Kendo UI for JQuery" that has an Angular demo, but also a "Kendo UI for Angular" site. Are you supposed to use the former for AngularJS only and the latter for Angular 5? If so, then I can just compare the syntax of those two demos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally Kendo UI offered Kendo UI (for jQuery) and everything else was just wrappers. Kendo UI for Angular seems to be a stand alone product, without any dependencies on jquery.

(In case for asp.net mvc, the kendo ui for mvc is just a wrapper around the base Kendo UI to offer developers the possibility to use the fluent syntax and C#.)

So to answer your question: If you plan to use Angular 2+, use the Kendo UI for Angular. It is specifically built to work without jQuery and with Typescript.

Comment: I'm using both versions because it's a hybrid app. I'm trying to determine whether we can move to Kendo UI now or if we should wait until everything is upgraded to Angular 5. If the syntax is the same, then maybe it doesn't matter when, but if it's different, then we may want to wait until it's all upgraded to Angular 5 so we don't have to redo some of the effort.

Comment: Specifically, I'm asking if the HTML syntax is the same or completely different.